# QDebug in friend method, with or without &?

Tags: qt4, qdebug

I've been using an overload for `QDebug` with `msvc2010` for a while:

```
friend QDebug &operator<<(QDebug &debug, const UsingClass &uc)
{
    debug << uc.stringForStreaming();
    return debug;
}
```

However, under `MinGW` with `gcc 4.6.2` this signature is not recognized and I have to change it to (no reference &):

```
friend QDebug operator<<(QDebug debug, const UsingClass &uc)
{
    debug << uc.stringForStreaming();
    return debug;
}
```

This suprises me somehow, since I have checked the headerfile for `QDebug` and the signatures there are basically references.

1. So what is the correct signature for overloading operators with `QDebug`? SO: [How to overload operator<< for qDebug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677577/how-to-overload-operator-for-qdebug) shows the one without reference, but does not tell why (different focus).
2. Why is the first signature (&) working with msvc2010, but fails with gcc?